# Doctrine - Symfony query error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**I do have an error and I don't know how to fix it**.

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery("UPDATE AppBundle:ChangeAPI SET `key`='asd123' WHERE `id` = 1");
$query->execute();
```

**My AppBundle:ChangeAPI**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="api")
 */
 class ChangeAPI
 {
     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
     protected $id;

     /**
      * The date on which the shipment has been created
      *
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="key")
      */
     protected $key;

     /** Creates a new standard ride */
     function __construct()
     {
     }
 }
```

**And this is my error result:**

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 31: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_SET, got '`'
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 31: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_SET, got '`'
QueryException: UPDATE AppBundle:ChangeAPI SET `key`='asd123' WHERE `id` = 1
```

**Can someone help me? Thanks.**

Comment: Should not it be `AppBundle.ChangeAPI` instead of `AppBundle:ChangeAPI`?

Comment: don't use the `\`` character

Comment: @SougataBose it's 100% ok with :

Comment: @Matteo. If i don't use ` without, this will be the error:
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 31: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_SET, got 'key

Comment: Ohk.. I didn't know that. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use query builder:

```
$entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->update('AppBundle:ChangeAPI', 'c')
    ->set('c.key', ':key')
    ->where('c.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('key', 'asd123')
    ->setParameter('id', 1)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Full reference http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 57: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'AND'

Comment: Edited sample. Where accepts parameters in a different way.

Comment: I've tried but..

An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE api SET key = ? WHERE id = ?' with params ["asd123", 1]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = 'asd123' WHERE id = 1' at line 1

Comment: I have more then 1 update queries, but i dont understand why this is not working, and the rest works !

Comment: Is your key column a string?

Comment: Yes, it is, and i solved it !. The problem was here:
 **@ORM\Column(type="string", name="key")** -- I replaced name="key" with name = " ` key ` "

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you for the queryBuilder xD

Answer (score 2):

Try using an alias:

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery("UPDATE AppBundle:ChangeAPI c SET c.key='asd123' WHERE c.id = 1");
$query->execute();
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

It's not MySQL query it's DQL query, therefore, don't use "`" character for name of cells.

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery("UPDATE AppBundle:ChangeAPI SET key='asd123' WHERE id = 1");
```

Comment: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 31: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_SET, got 'key'

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create a query for this through Doctrine. Another way would be to change these in your normal controller methods.

In your controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/{id}"), name="app_edit_API")
 * @param ChangeAPI
 */
public function editAPIAction(ChangeAPI $changeAPI)
{
     $changeAPI->setKey('asd123');
     $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
}
```

Are you using a form or is this maybe a command? If so then Palethorn's answer above is a better alternative.